# Scrolling Xamarin.Forms Syncfusion Chart

Tags: charts, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I have a Xamarin.Forms Android app with a Syncfusion chart to display some data.

Am I able to programmatic scroll the chart to the end preferable using Bindings to the last item in the ItemsSource?

So given a Area Series with an item source of ChartModel:

```
        <chart:AreaSeries   
            ItemsSource ="{Binding ChartModel,Mode=TwoWay}"
            XBindingPath="PaymentDateFormatted"
            YBindingPath="PaidAmount"               
            Color="#9cd58e">
                .....
            </chart:AreaSeries>
```

When the chart displays I would like it to be scrolled to the end by default:

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

This requirement can be achieved by using **AutoScrollingDelta** feature. Use the below code.

**Code:**

DateTimeAxis xAxis = new DateTimeAxis();

xAxis.AutoScrollingDeltaType = DateTimeDeltaType.Days;

xAxis.AutoScrollingDelta = 7;

chart.PrimaryAxis = xAxis;

**AutoScrolling:**

**AutoScrollingDelta** feature in **SfChart** is used to ensure that the specified range of data is always visible in the chart and scroll to view the remaining data points.
Additionally,  we recommend you to refer the below knowledge base link to know more about this feature.

**KB Link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/7721/how-to-display-fixed-number-of-data-points-in-sfchart

Regards,

Saravana Pandian M.

Comment: Hey maye thanks for your reply.  I am using an area series and xaml. Is there any waybti achieve what you suggest in xaml?  Ill definitely try your suggestion in the code behind.  Thanks